# Python Logging, Logger and Inheritance

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Hi I'm wondering why the `self.logger` is not overridden by the derived classes?

```py
import logging
import sys

logFormat = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s] %(message)s'
dateFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logFormatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=logFormat, datefmt=dateFormat)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)


class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Person')
        self.Person = 'Person'
        self.Print()

    def Print(self):
        self.logger.debug('Hello From Person')
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(self.__dict__))

class Parent(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        #Person.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Parent')
        self.Parent = 'Parent'
        self.Print()
    def Print(self):
        self.logger.debug('Hello from Parent')
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(self.__dict__))

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        #Parent.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Child')
        self.Child = 'Child'
        self.Print()
    def Print(self):
        self.logger.debug('Hello from Child')
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(self.__dict__))


root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

p = Person()
print('Person Class Created.')

c = Child()
print('Child Class Created.')
```

The output of the code is:

```
2023-04-27 10:50:24.066 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] Hello From Person
2023-04-27 10:50:24.066 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] {'logger': <logging.Logger object at 0x00000266802FF780>, 'Person': 'Person'}
Person Class Created.
2023-04-27 10:50:24.066 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] Hello from Child
2023-04-27 10:50:24.066 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] {'logger': <logging.Logger object at 0x00000266802FF780>, 'Person': 'Person'}
2023-04-27 10:50:24.066 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] Hello from Child
2023-04-27 10:50:24.066 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] {'logger': <logging.Logger object at 0x00000266802FF828>, 'Parent': 'Parent', 'Person': 'Person'}
2023-04-27 10:50:24.067 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] Hello from Child
2023-04-27 10:50:24.067 DEBUG    [logTest.py:Print] {'logger': <logging.Logger object at 0x00000266802FF860>, 'Child': 'Child', 'Parent': 'Parent', 'Person': 'Person'}
```

Notice that the `logger` object in `Person` has a different address than the `Child`. The `print` functions are all called from the `Child` function as you would expect but the `logger` has a different at each inheritance..

Can someone explain or fix?

Comment: You don't change the `logger` attribute until after `super().__init__` returns, by which point the `Print` method has already been called using the value set by `Parent.__init__`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this occurs because you are logging the address of the strings
`'Person', 'Parent' and 'Child'`
That is why Person logs have the the same address:

```
<logging.Logger object at 0x00000266802FF780>, 'Person': 'Person'}
...
<logging.Logger object at 0x00000266802FF780>, 'Person': 'Person'}
```

So you have to change the above strings to `self.__str__()` in orrder to get the same address:

```
import logging
import sys

logFormat = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s] %(message)s'
dateFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logFormatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=logFormat, datefmt=dateFormat)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)


class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__str__())
        self.Person = 'Person'
        self.Print()

    def Print(self):
        print('I am on Person')
        self.logger.debug('Hello From Person')
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(self.__dict__))


class Parent(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        # Person.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__str__())
        self.Parent = 'Parent'
        self.Print()

    def Print(self):
        print('I am on Parent')
        self.logger.debug('Hello from Parent')
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(self.__dict__))


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        # Parent.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__str__())
        self.Child = 'Child'
        self.Print()

    def Print(self):
        print('I am on Child')
        self.logger.debug('Hello from Child')
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(self.__dict__))


root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

p = Person()
print('Person Class Created.')

c = Child()
print('Child Class Created.')
```

**Output:**

```
I am on Person
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] Hello From Person
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] {'logger': <Logger <__main__.Person object at 0x000001CDCFE84910> (DEBUG)>, 'Person': 'Person'}
Person Class Created.
I am on Child
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] Hello from Child
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] {'logger': <Logger <__main__.Child object at 0x000001CDCFE84940> (DEBUG)>, 'Person': 'Person'}
I am on Child
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] Hello from Child
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] {'logger': <Logger <__main__.Child object at 0x000001CDCFE84940> (DEBUG)>, 'Person': 'Person', 'Parent': 'Parent'}
I am on Child
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] Hello from Child
2023-04-27 23:29:48.677 DEBUG    [stackOverflow.py:Print] {'logger': <Logger <__main__.Child object at 0x000001CDCFE84940> (DEBUG)>, 'Person': 'Person', 'Parent': 'Parent', 'Child': 'Child'}
Child Class Created.
```

Comment: That is very useful. Normally I put each class in its own py file. with self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__). I would then get output that have the file name. But when a base class's method outputs a log, it uses it's file name not the derived. Can you explain why?

Comment: @DanielPortugal Could you please add a reproducible example in order to fully understand your question?